# How AudioSource.VOICE_PERFORMANCE ensure minimize latency

Tags: android, audio, low-latency, audio-source

According android dev website, use AudioSource.VOICE_PERFORMANCE can ensure capture path will minimize latency and coupling with playback path.
I try to find the answer by reading android source code, especially AudioFinger implementation, but can't get valuable clue. And I find there is a message in logcat: "audio_hw_primary        android.hardware.audio@2.0-service   D  start_input_stream: enter: stream(0xe8682500)usecase(20: audio-record)".
The "usecase" is the same with AudioSource.DEFAULT, but opensl is "low-latency-record". So I was even more confused，how android system make "minimize latency"?